# String::Format to split line in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, string-formatting

I am getting error from the following code (visual c++), I am doing something wrong :(.

```
while (readString->Peek() > -1)
                {
                    String^ WholeLine = (readString->ReadLine());
                    array<String^>^ words = WholeLine->Split(' ');
                    FirstString = String::Format("{0}", words);                     
                    SecondString = String::Format("{1}", words);
```

When I run the program I get:

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Or is there any other way that I can split the line other than String::Format?

Or is there are way that I can assign variables in visual c++ using while loop such as in c++?

```
while (fin >> var1 >> var2)
```

Thanks you very much in advance...

Comment: `FirstString = words[0]; SecondString = words[1];`

Comment: Thanks...it does assign the variables but I still get an exception, this time it is: Index was outside the bounds of the array. I think I have to change the way I split the line.

Comment: This means you do not in fact have a space in the line. Perhaps the line is empty. You probably want to check `words.length` before accessing its elements.

Comment: I've tested with ";" instead of space and still the same. There is something with the array pointer, I am trying to find out... array<String^>^ words = WholeLine->Split(' ');